# PHP Imagick Composite Losing sRGB color quality why?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have a simple watermark script which works well, but it seems adobe sRGB images lose color quality.

Running a watermark command via shell/imagemagick works great - no color quality lost.

Using imagick, however, dulls the color.

Here is the series of commands I use:

```
    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->readImage($this->source_path);

    $watermark = new Imagick();
    $watermark->readImage($this->watermark_path);

    // how big are the images?
    $iWidth = $image->getImageWidth();
    $iHeight = $image->getImageHeight();
    $wWidth = $watermark->getImageWidth();
    $wHeight = $watermark->getImageHeight();

    // calculate the position
    $x = ( $iWidth - $wWidth ) / 2;
    $y = ( $iHeight - $wHeight ) / 2;

    //we have to make the transparency go to white, or it will become an awefull black color in jpeg version        
    $white = new Imagick();

    $white->newImage($image->getImageWidth(), $image->getImageHeight(), "white");

    if ($image->getImageColorspace() == Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB) { 
        $watermark->setColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
        $white->setColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
    }

    $white->compositeimage($image, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);

    //now apply watermark
    $white->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $x, $y);

    //save
    $white->writeImage($this->destination);

    //save memory
    $image->destroy();
    $white->destroy();
```

I made a half-educated assumption that if I convert the other two elements (the white background, and the png overlay) to sRGB, nothing would be lost. I did that with this segment here:

```
    if ($image->getImageColorspace() == Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB) { 
        $watermark->setColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
        $white->setColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
    }
```

...Still no shrimp Lieutenant Dan...

Is there any possible way around this issue? Ideally I'd like to use the shell commands, but I'd like to perfect the imagick version for those who do not have shell access in their environments.

Comment: Can you provide an example image and the processed version?

Comment: Thanks - solved it yesterday and was just going to post the solution. Sadly the example in question is a copyrighted work so I can't make it public.

Comment: "Still no shrimp Lieutenant Dan" - awesome

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/imagick.compositeimage.php (was like a scavenger hunt!)

The solution as stated in above link:

> You might need to set the colorspace the same when composing two
>   images over each other

```
<?php
//Creating two Imagick object
$first = new Imagick('first.jpg');
$second = new Imagick('second.jpg');

// Set the colorspace to the same value
$first->setImageColorspace($second->getImageColorspace() );

//Second image is put on top of the first
$first->compositeImage($second, $second->getImageCompose(), 5, 5);

//new image is saved as final.jpg
$first->writeImage('final.jpg');
?>
```